# Force returned date by web server

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an application with test suite. These test need to be runned in specific period (a date between 01-01-2012 and 31-12-2012).

Is it possible to force returned date (to scripts like php, python) instead system clock in a virtual host ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the system clock?

Comment: No, when a scipt (php, python, etc) ask date: return a forced date instead system clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible, you just have to write the logic to do it. Look into the [`mktime`](http://php.net/mktime) function for php. Not sure on python.

But aside from that, I am not sure what your real question is (taking that I do not think English is your first language). You can always change the system clock of the VPS to be the time you need prior to running the script.